# Sharing C++ classes across DLLs

Tags: c++, dll

Simply enough, I have a class library that needs to be shared across DLLs. I want to avoid exporting that library to a separate DLL, if possible.

More specifically, I have an common interface that extensions are supposed to implement, and provide a factory for the derived class. That is simple to do by making a common header file with a pure virtual class. However, all derived classes will share a few implementation details, and I wanted to include them in the base class definition to avoid code duplication.

Here's a specific example that seems to work so far in VC2010, but I want to make sure it won't break when different compilers are involved.

Both modules share the following two files:

```
// Object.h
class Object
{
protected:
  int x;
public:
  Object();
  virtual int Foo() = 0;
  void Bar();
};
typedef Object* (*ObjectFactory)();

// Object.cpp
Object::Object()
{
  x = 0;
}
void Object::Bar()
{
  x++;
}
```

Library main cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "object.h"

class Derived : public Object
{
public:
  int Foo()
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Object* CreateObject()
{
  return new Derived;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
  return TRUE;
}
```

Main module:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "object.h"

int main()
{
  HMODULE module = LoadLibrary("test_dll.dll");
  ObjectFactory factory = (ObjectFactory) GetProcAddress(module, "CreateObject");
  Object* o = factory();
  o->Bar();
  int x = o->Foo(); // returns 2, as expected
  FreeLibrary(module);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not add `Object::Bar` in the main module's header and implementation?

Comment: Make a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for it!!

Comment: _'Then I include both Object.h and Object.cpp in every module. Would that work?'_ No! Definitely not ...

Comment: Why not, what would happen when I try to load the module DLL? Since I don't export anything except the factory function, it shouldn't care about anything else, no?

Comment: ... you should share class declaration only via headers between modules. Their definitions should be linked only **once**.

Comment: I don't see how facade would help. I need to be able to load a library that implements an interface and provides a factory for it.

Comment: It would help in general for such designs. This was a side note, not an answer to your specific problem.

Comment: Should any instances of the classes declared in `Object.h` be shared across module boundaries directly or indirectly? I'm not sure what the linker does if it sees multiple defintions for the class across shared libraries linked together. I'd say that calls for trouble.

Comment: Why should the linker be concerned, if the other module doesn't even exist when the main module is linked? I'll update the question with a specific example that works in VC2010.

Comment: I'd be concerned what happens when the library is loaded and linked dynamically with `dlopen()`. There might be confusion from where to resolve such class instances. I'm not so sure about that, but I vaguely remember about situations where this lead to trouble. On the other hand the compiler/linker/dynamic linker should provide solutions for handling e.g. template code across shared library, which would lead to the same situation more or less.

Comment: I think the problem might be to **guarantee** all modules see the same version of `Object.h`, `Object.cpp`, maybe just link it as a static library has the same effect, but serves better for versioning.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they see, to them an `Object` is just a chunk of memory with a vtable and an int. Memory representation _should_ be consistent across compilers because COM does just that (minus the member variable). It doesn't matter if they have a different version of `Bar` because all it does is modify an `int` at a certain offset.

Comment: Maybe **just you try** with different compilers (GCC, Clang) if it works properly, and ask for specific problems then ...